# Series of powers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

Consider the sequences $a_k,b_k\in\mathbb R$ and let $N\in\mathbb N$. Do series of the form
$$f(n)=\sum_{k=1}^N a_k\,{b_k}^n$$
have a name? They seem quite a natural object to study but I'm not sure what to search for online and I'm not coming across them.

I want to prove the following fact about them: if two series of the above form, $f(n)=
\sum_{k=1}^{N} a_k\,{b_k}^n$ and $g(n)=
\sum_{k=1}^{M} c_k\,{d_k}^n$ satisfy $f(n)=g(n)$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$, then $N=M$, $a_k=c_k$ and $b_k=d_k$ for all $1\leqslant k\leqslant N$.

---

Here is my idea: if $f(n)=g(n)$ for all $n$, then $f(n)/g(n)\to 1$, but the dominant term $a_r{b_r}^n$ in the numerator and dominant term $c_s{d_s}^n$ in the denominator will cause $f(n)/g(n)$ to diverge unless $b_r=d_s$, in which case the limit is $a_r/c_s$, but since the limit is $1$ this forces $a_r=c_s$ too.

If we subtract the dominant terms off, considering $[f(n)-a_r{b_r}^n]/[g(n)-a_r{b_r}^n]$, the same argument establishes the analogous fact for the next pair of dominant terms, and so on, until we either run out of terms from either the numerator and the denominator. But if we run out, then we get a limit of the form $\frac0\infty$ or $\frac\infty0$, which contradicts that $f$ and $g$ coincide.

Is there a nicer way to prove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is an answer with some extra conditions which we worked out in the comments of the counter-example to the original question.

Let
$$\begin{align}
f(n) &= \sum_{k=1}^N a_k b_k^n \\
g(n) &= \sum_{k=1}^M c_k d_k^n
\end{align}$$
be two functions with $N$-tuples $(a_k)$, $(b_k)$ and $M$-tuples $(c_k)$, $(d_k)$ of non-zero real (or complex) numbers such that:

$$|b_k| > |b_{k+1}|\qquad\text{and}\qquad |d_k| > |d_{k+1}|.\tag 1$$

Then we have
$$ f(n) = g(n) \ \forall n\in\Bbb N \qquad\implies\qquad  M=N, a_k=c_k, b_k=d_k.$$

**Proof:** We have

$$\begin{align}
f(n) &= \sum_{k=1}^N a_k b_k^n \\
&= a_1b_1^n + \sum_{k=2}^N a_k b_k^n \\
&= b_1^n \left(a_1 + \sum_{k=2}^N a_k (b_k/b_1)^n \right)\\
&= d_1^n \left(c_1 + \sum_{k=2}^M c_k (d_k/d_1)^n \right) = g(n)\\
\end{align}$$
The remaining sums starting at $k=2$ converge to zero for $n\to\infty$ due to $(1)$, or are already zero if a sum is empty. Thus we can divide both sides provided $n$ is large enough:

$$
\left(\frac{b_1}{d_1}\right)^{\!n}
= \frac{c_1 + \sum_{k=2}^M c_k (d_k/d_1)^n}{a_1 + \sum_{k=2}^N a_k (b_k/b_1)^n}
\quad\stackrel{\text{as }n\to\infty}\longrightarrow \quad \frac{c_1}{a_1} \notin\{0,\infty\}
$$
As the limit of the right side exists and is non-zero, it must also exist for the left side.  The only way that $(b_1/d_1)^n$ converges to a finite, non-zero value is to have $b_1=d_1$ and hence also that $a_1=c_1$.

The proof is then finished by repeating the same argument where the 1st summand of either function is dropped because they equal each other, so we are left with sums that are 1 term shorter.

One residual case is remaining if $N\neq M$ if one sum is exhausted (empty) and the other is not. I'll leave that as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

That's not correct? Take for example:

**Edit2:** So you adjusted the conditions *again* so that no zeros are allowed in any of $a_k$ or $b_k$.  As an updated counter-example, take $N=M$ even and:

$$\begin{align}
a &= a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, \dots, a_{N-1}, a_N\\
b &= b_1, b_2, b_3, b_4, \dots, b_{N-1}, b_N\\
c &= a_2, a_1, a_4, a_3, \dots, a_N, a_{N-1}\\
d &= b_2, b_1, b_4, b_3, \dots, b_N, b_{N-1}\\
\end{align}$$
and such that $a_k > 0$, $b_k > 0$ and

- $a_k\neq a_{k+1}$ for any odd $k$, and
- $b_k\neq b_{k+1}$ for any odd $k$.

This means you can just swap values at odd and even indices.
Actually, you can apply any non-trivial permutation $\sigma\in{\cal S}_N$ to get a similar counter example, in particular you can pick a permutation that has no fixed-points.

The only case when there is no non-trivial permutation is the case $N=M=1$ which is not very interesting.

Comment: Ah, I suppose I tacitly assumed that $f(n), g(n)>0$ for all $n$. I think it's true in that case, no? What do you think of the proof I added?

Comment: @lamasabachthani If $a_k$ and $b_k$ are complex numbers, then $f(n)$ is also a complex number and your condition $f(n) > 0$ is not clear.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin What if we work only with real numbers then?

Comment: @lamasabachthani: I adjusted my counter-example.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts I want to salvage the argument somehow  
What if all of the $a_k,b_k,c_k,d_k$ are positive?

Comment: @lamasabachthani: I adjusted my counter example to a very generic argument.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts Thank you :)
So what is wrong with my proof?

Comment: @lamasabachthani: Maybe the counter-example helps to find where the "proof" breaks.  And you cannot conclude anything from $f/g\to1$ because that's trivial due to $f=g$. And there are other lines of infinitely many counter-examples like $b^n+b^n=2b^n$. Your "dominating term" argument does not work at all.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts I am now understanding what you mean exactly. In my case I don't actually care about the precise order of the terms (you're right of course with your counter example), what I care about is that the numerator and the denominator are essentially the same expression. So my formulation is incorrect; what I meant to say is that if we pair them up correctly, $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ consist of the same $a_i{b_i}^k$'s. My proof does achieve this, no?

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts I think i can account for this in my current formulation by insisting that the $a_n$'s and $b_n$'s are written in strictly decreasing order.

Comment: @lamasabachthani: Then you'd neet that the $a_k$ are decreasing **and** the $b_k$ are decreasing, because otherwise you won't get an ordering.  This takes away much of the power; with each of my examples you have to cut down the generality of your claims... This may be the reason why there is no existing theory.

Comment: @lamasabachthani: ..maybe what works is to 1) Have all $a$'s and $b$'s non-zero. 2) Have the $b$'s strictly increasing (or decreasing).

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts Yes I think you're right, once the exponential terms (the ${b_i}^k$s) are ordered then the corresponding coefficients should be determined also. The reason I am studying this sum is that one can express the number of walks of length $n$ in a graph in this form.